# Reproduce all attributes in XML conversion using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I try to convert XML to XHTML using XSLT.
The XML code provided contains tables, with attributes that I have to reproduce :

XML Code :

```
...
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="70" valign="middle" align="center">
       Hi 
    </td>
    <td width="95" valign="middle" align="center">
       Ho 
    </td>
    <td width="130" valign="middle" align="center">
       Hu 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="70" valign="middle" align="center" class="text1">
       hihihi
    </td> 
    <td width="95" valign="middle" align="right" class="text1">
       hohoho
    </td> 
    <td width="130" valign="middle" align="center" class="text1">
       huhuhu
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
...
```

For now, I use that XSL code :

```
...
<xsl:template match="table">
<table><xsl:apply-templates /></table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
<tr><xsl:apply-templates /></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td">
<td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
</xsl:template>
...
```

Any idea about reproducing all cells attributes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="table | tr | td">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```